Uploading shapefile to GEE
I tried to upload a shapefile to GEE but I received the error

The file list should have one file with the following
extention(s):.shp or zip



You haven't added boundary.shp

Zip shapefile with shx, dbf, prj and shp files and upload again.

The .sbn and .shp.xml are not necessary, but the .shp is required.

According to the specification, a shapefile must contain at least three files, with the same file name prefix and the following suffixes:

.shp - The geometry data
.shx - The offset file for direct read access to .shp
.dbf - The attributes (in dBase-III+ format)

In addition, if ArcGIS tools were involved, there should be a fourth file:

.prj - The coordinate reference specification file (Esri projection string)

There are additional files created by Esri tools, including:

.cpg - Codepage file for the character set agnostic dBase file
.sbn - Spatial index file (used only by Esri tools)
.sbx - The offset file for the .sbn file
.shp.xml - An XML format metadata file (does not contain geometry)

QGIS can generate its own parallel files:

.qix - Spatial index file
.qpj - QGIS coordinate reference file (OGC WKT format)

Only the .shp and .dbf are absolutely essential, since the .shx can be reproduced by scanning the .shp contents (and, technically, you can mock up a dBase-III with the same number of records if you don't care that all attributes would be lost).
Google Earth Engine is reporting that you didn't include a .shp in your zipfile, which is like showing up at a prom date's house with the flower vase, but no flowers. The fix is to generate a zipfile with at least the required files. The UI provides a list of acceptable extras.
